# Drools Accumulate Issues

Tags: drools

I am having trouble with Drools 5.4 accumulate. What I would like to do is fired a rule when a number of events happen within a given time:

```
when

$things : List() from collect (TimedThings () over window:time(5ms)) 

$thing_list  : List(size > 10) from accumulate(
        $thing : TimedThings (eval(testMe(attribute, "1"))) from $things,
        collectList($thing)
            )
then
```

Now I would expect this to only fire when there are 10 things in thing_list but I am seeing it fire with less than 10 things.

Is my rule incorrect?

Comment: I am trying to solve a similar problem. Did you get through with it?